# MarkUp Calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a calculator (Javascript or HTML) with an opportunity to calculate additional markups to jobs. Different markups to the job:

- Without exception, there is a flat markup on all jobs of 5%
- For each person that needs to work on the job, there is a markup of 1.2%

Markups are also added depending on the types of materials involved:

- If factory is involved, there is an immediate 7.5% markup
- For drinks, there is a 13% markup
- Home appliances require a 2% markup
- Everything else, there is no markup

The flat markup is calculated first and then all other markups are calculated on top of the base price plus flat markup.

Whatever I did, does not work. I am a beginner, so any help is appreciated.

### Example 1:

```
Input:  $1,299.99, 3 people, drinks
```

3 people: 1299.99*(1.2%*3)
Drinks: 1299.99*13%

Add 5% to the total at the end

```
Output: $1,591.58
```

Comment: Can you give more examples of input data?

Comment: You should post what you have tried, even though it did not work